# How can i make a click on row in a table to call controller action?

Tags: grails

I am new to grails. I have started it with a small application.I am not getting how to make a click on row to call controller action.

I tried the following with no success:

```
<tr onmouseover="ChangeColor(this, true);" 
     onmouseout="ChangeColor(this, false);" 
     onclick="${remoteFuction(action: 'modify', id: address.id)}"/>

<tr onmouseover="ChangeColor(this, true);" 
     onmouseout="ChangeColor(this, false);"
     onclick="<g:remoteFunction action='modify' id='${address.id}'/>">

</tr>
```

Is there any solution exist for this issue in grails?

Comment: Please provide a GSP code sample and quote it with stackoverflow's markup.

Answer (score 2):

This works fine with Grails 2.1:

```
<tr onclick='document.location = "<g:createLink action='show' id='${clientInstance.id}'/>" '> ... </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Googling on [remoteFunction finds its manual page](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/remoteFunction.html), it has a pretty good set of examples.

Just don't use tags, `remoteFuction()` is available as a function from GSP strings.

Answer (score 0):

You were nearly right, I think this should work:

```
<tr onmouseover="ChangeColor(this, true);" 
         onmouseout="ChangeColor(this, false);" 
         onclick="${remoteFuction(action: 'modify', id: address.id)}"/>
```

### Update

The suggestion above doesn't work (I suspect it's a Grails bug, so [I've created an issue in their bug-tracker](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-7489)). As an alternative, you can use the uglier tag-form of the `removeFunction` tag

```
<tr onmouseover="ChangeColor(this, true);" 
         onmouseout="ChangeColor(this, false);"
         onclick="<g:remoteFunction action='modify' id='${address.id}'/>">

</tr>
```

### Aside

you should use `<tr></tr>` rather than `<tr/>`

Comment: I tried with this but i got error as: No signature of method: remoteFunction is applicable for arguments types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[action:modify, id:1]]

Comment: Please try my alternative suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You would also like to change cursor to hand to your row

```
   <tr style="cursor: pointer;" onclick='document.location = "<g:createLink action='show' id='${product.id}'/>"'>
```